# Getting error while installing Acquia CLI

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, cloud

I run this 4 commands -

Downloading the latest version of Acquia CLI.

curl -OL https://github.com/acquia/cli/releases/latest/download/acli.phar.

chmod +x acli.phar

mv acli.phar /usr/local/bin/acli

And after completing this if I am trying to run acli in my ubantu terminal I am getting error -

## ***Box Requirements Checker

> Using PHP 7.4.3
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
> /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
> Checking Box requirements:
> .....E
> [ERROR] Your system is not ready to run the application.
> Fix the following mandatory requirements:
> =========================================

- The package "zumba/amplitude-php" requires the extension "curl". Enable it or install a polyfill.***

Comment: It basically tells you that a specific PHP extension is expected to be installed. `apt install php-curl` (or `apt install php7.4-curl`) should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically we have to install the extension and command is -

```
apt install php7.4-curl
```